# Translate musical sheet into audio

Tags: piano, sheet-music

I have a tiny musical sheet that I would like to find out how it sounds.

Is there a way to transcribe this into something that I could listen to? Sound-quality is not relevant of course, I would be fine with some online piano simulator link too, I just cannot deal with the notation below.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about something that could read the image as is, or are you looking for software that allows you to re-write (transcribe) the notation yourself and then play it back to you?

Comment: I would like to find out how this little piece of music sounds. By any means. Probably somebody with 2 minutes of freetime could type it into some online piano simulator or something. Not sure really.

Comment: Got it. This site isn't really set up for that kind of question, but you could try posting in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room); I've seen people occasionally post homemade recordings there.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a good question for this site, since the "music practice and theory" answer to this general problem would be to learn to read music, and it seems that you just want a quick translation of one snippet.  Your best bet may be to ask someone you know who can read music to demonstrate what it sounds like.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.organum.playscore

Comment: @GergelyBacso you could type it over into musescore. It's a free music notation program, but it also allows you to play the score.